# How to auto number across two columns in a table

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

[image]

The normal auto numbering is row by row just like the above one, how can I make it column by column like the following?

[image]

I did the second one manually, because I don't know how to do it automatically. Any solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of this procedure, for a table with 4 rows:

- Select the first column and select *Numbering* in *Home > Paragraph*
- Select the second column and select *Numbering*, giving:

  [image]
- Right-click the first sequence number on the second column and select
  "Set Numbering Value..."
- Set the starting value to 5, giving:

  [image]